# Theme imports all images in image file upon launch, and slows down the running of project, via netbeans. How to avoid?

Tags: image, codenameone, designer

Great Tool and thank you for your considerable time and effort! I've noticed is upon launching the Designer to attempt deleting unused images: once the Designer is launched, but is still loading the Theme, I can select the "Delete unused images" which launches its interface(list). But if I let the Theme load then the Delete unused images list will not appear. Once Theme has loaded it is populates with images, all with the Selector name as 'import-############" So the Theme is using these images... even if I don't intend to. I have designed all of the interface layout in the Gui Builder. If i remove one of these 'import-############" files and save then try run project, the project does run, eventually(10minutes+ before simulator launch) but continually gives the following: Warning: loading large images using EncodedImage.create(InputStream) might lead to memory issues, try using EncodedImage.create(InputStream, int). Too further this diagnosis if I launch designer and allow Theme to load (2-3minutes aprox) and click save then try to run project, so deleting nothing, I get the same error message. So it seems to me when I launch Designer, it imports these images which then causes the error/warning. So is there a way to avoid this importing of images and remove the unwanted images? In contrast if I don't launch Designer, and straight run the project in Netbeans. I don't get the error/warning and the project launches in simulator much speedier. For each of these scenarios I have copied a new project folder then launched netbeans. This folder, the project would not have had the Designer launched prior.
If I manually remove unused images I get null pointer Exception errors...

Re Shai's comments on 26/May

So when I delete the images and both "theme.res" files the project fails to run and generates following output:

```
Generating GUI sources
timeStr=1.0.0-1589639113000-1588429678000, lastTime=1.0.0-1589639113000-1588429678000
CIMenus.java unmodified, skipping
timeStr=1.0.0-1588250408000-1588255873000, lastTime=1.0.0-1588250408000-1588255873000
SplashForm.java unmodified, skipping
timeStr=1.0.0-1589730011000-1589485802000, lastTime=1.0.0-1589730011000-1589485802000
PractiseArea.java unmodified, skipping
timeStr=1.0.0-1588621870000-1588255973000, lastTime=1.0.0-1588621870000-1588255973000
Login.java unmodified, skipping
timeStr=1.0.0-1588507007000-1588506037000, lastTime=1.0.0-1588507007000-1588506037000
CISpaceInvader.java unmodified, skipping
timeStr=1.0.0-1589637149000-1588621944000, lastTime=1.0.0-1589637149000-1588621944000
LessonPlayer.java unmodified, skipping
init:
Deleting: /Users/andrew/netbeans-workspace/CrackinIt/build/built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: /Users/andrew/netbeans-workspace/CrackinIt/build/built-jar.properties
JavaFX is loaded
Retina Scale: 2.0
Updating merge file /Users/andrew/netbeans-workspace/CrackinIt/css/theme.css.merged
Input: /Users/andrew/netbeans-workspace/CrackinIt/css/theme.css
Output: /Users/andrew/netbeans-workspace/CrackinIt/src/theme.res
Acquiring lock on CSS checksums file /Users/andrew/netbeans-workspace/CrackinIt/.cn1_css_checksums...
Lock obtained
An error occurred while updating resources for UIID import-1588534357646.  Processing property bgImage
Releasing lock
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/andrew/netbeans-workspace/CrackinIt/css/images/Button1-7.png (No such file or directory)
    at com.codename1.designer.css.CSSTheme.getBackgroundImage(CSSTheme.java:2310)
    at com.codename1.designer.css.CSSTheme.getBackgroundImages(CSSTheme.java:1981)
    at com.codename1.designer.css.CSSTheme.updateResources(CSSTheme.java:1678)
    at com.codename1.designer.css.CN1CSSCLI.compile(CN1CSSCLI.java:535)
    at com.codename1.designer.css.CN1CSSCLI.main(CN1CSSCLI.java:390)
    at com.codename1.designer.ResourceEditorApp.main(ResourceEditorApp.java:556)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/andrew/netbeans-workspace/CrackinIt/css/images/Button1-7.png (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at com.codename1.designer.css.CSSTheme.getBackgroundImage(CSSTheme.java:2258)
    ... 5 more
/Users/andrew/netbeans-workspace/CrackinIt/build.xml:628: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 4 seconds)
```

When I delete the images and the "theme.res" file from the "build" folder the project launches with a "theme.res"(res) file in the project viewer, project runs. If I launch the res file and allow it to load theme then save and exit from the designer, the project runs.

But if I launch the res file and allow it to load theme then remove one of the images that isn't being used, save and exit from the designer, the "theme.res" file is gone from project viewer. When attempting to run project, it now gives the following:

```
ant -f /Users/andrew/netbeans-workspace/CrackinIt -Dnb.internal.action.name=run run
Generating GUI sources
timeStr=1.0.0-1589639113000-1588429678000, lastTime=1.0.0-1589639113000-1588429678000
CIMenus.java unmodified, skipping
timeStr=1.0.0-1588250408000-1588255873000, lastTime=1.0.0-1588250408000-1588255873000
SplashForm.java unmodified, skipping
timeStr=1.0.0-1589730011000-1589485802000, lastTime=1.0.0-1589730011000-1589485802000
PractiseArea.java unmodified, skipping
timeStr=1.0.0-1588621870000-1588255973000, lastTime=1.0.0-1588621870000-1588255973000
Login.java unmodified, skipping
timeStr=1.0.0-1588507007000-1588506037000, lastTime=1.0.0-1588507007000-1588506037000
CISpaceInvader.java unmodified, skipping
timeStr=1.0.0-1589637149000-1588621944000, lastTime=1.0.0-1589637149000-1588621944000
LessonPlayer.java unmodified, skipping
init:
Deleting: /Users/andrew/netbeans-workspace/CrackinIt/build/built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: /Users/andrew/netbeans-workspace/CrackinIt/build/built-jar.properties
JavaFX is loaded
Retina Scale: 2.0
Updating merge file /Users/andrew/netbeans-workspace/CrackinIt/css/theme.css.merged
Input: /Users/andrew/netbeans-workspace/CrackinIt/css/theme.css
Output: /Users/andrew/netbeans-workspace/CrackinIt/src/theme.res
Acquiring lock on CSS checksums file /Users/andrew/netbeans-workspace/CrackinIt/.cn1_css_checksums...
Lock obtained
/Users/andrew/netbeans-workspace/CrackinIt/src/theme.res has been modified since it was last compiled.  Making copy at /Users/andrew/netbeans-workspace/CrackinIt/css/.backups/theme.res.1590562229494.bak
An error occurred while updating resources for UIID import-1588534357646.  Processing property bgImage
Releasing lock
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/andrew/netbeans-workspace/CrackinIt/css/images/Button1-7.png (No such file or directory)
    at com.codename1.designer.css.CSSTheme.getBackgroundImage(CSSTheme.java:2310)
    at com.codename1.designer.css.CSSTheme.getBackgroundImages(CSSTheme.java:1981)
    at com.codename1.designer.css.CSSTheme.updateResources(CSSTheme.java:1678)
    at com.codename1.designer.css.CN1CSSCLI.compile(CN1CSSCLI.java:535)
    at com.codename1.designer.css.CN1CSSCLI.main(CN1CSSCLI.java:390)
    at com.codename1.designer.ResourceEditorApp.main(ResourceEditorApp.java:556)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/andrew/netbeans-workspace/CrackinIt/css/images/Button1-7.png (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at com.codename1.designer.css.CSSTheme.getBackgroundImage(CSSTheme.java:2258)
    ... 5 more
/Users/andrew/netbeans-workspace/CrackinIt/build.xml:628: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

The unused image files aren't in the project folder

Comment: We'll need more information about your project. Did you use CSS to build the theme? How did you create the theme which images did you use?

Comment: I avoided using Designer completely the images of concern are in the image folder in the css folder. I diid all the interface design via the Gui-builder. From the Gui-builder I imported the image files. It is when I want use the Delete unused images that I have to launch the Designer which generates the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

This will never work for you.

Once you use CSS the designer is only useful for viewing the generated file. But since the CSS regenerates the resource file any change you make will be discarded. You need to delete the images you no longer use manually from the CSS images directory then physically delete the res file to make sure it's regenerated from scratch.

Comment: Thanks thus far I have generated an error, just to clarify it is the Theme.res file I delete and I do this manually??

Comment: I seem to have two "theme.res" files in the project folder. The first is in the "src" folder and the second "theme.res" is in build/classes/ folder which of these if not both should be deleted?

Comment: So when I delete both "theme.res" files the project fails to run and generates following output:

Comment: This file is clearly used by the theme. It's either a border image implicitly generated by the CSS or something you reference from your CSS.